# How to change opera for mac's search engine for special dial page?

Tags: opera

I can change the address bar search engine but it doesn't effect the special dial search engine. I like to know where to find its setting. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can not change that search box. Even if you change the browser's search engine, it does not affect that special box.